# Scientific names of taxids with kraken 2.0.8 beta, command kraken2 --use-names error

Tags: database

I am running kraken 2.0.8 beta to do taxonomic classification of micorbiota data coming from a MinION run based on the 16S gene. To do so I am using the pre-bult kraken SILVA  database. I managed to get the standard kraken output format but now I would like to replace the taxonomic ID column with  scientific names. According to the manual (https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/kraken2/index.shtml?t=manual) I should run the command:

kraken2 --use-names

but it gives the error:

command kraken2 not found

I also tried variants such as:

./kraken 2 --use-names

but still it gives an error.

I also tried without kraken2 and thus,

--use-names

but it gives this error:

--use-names command not found

Do you have any idea how I can proceed?

In the picture you can see that everything works to obtain the standard kraken output for barcode 76. But if I try to implement the --use-names command then it does not work

[image: ERROR THAT I GET IF I TRY TO USE THE --USE-NAMES COMMAND]

I solved the problem: it was a matter of the position of the --use-names command. By changing position (see picture) it worked.
[image: problem solved picture]

Comment: What is the output when you run `which kraken2` in your command line?

Comment: Simply nothing happens

Comment: Install kraken2 and add the executable to your path as per https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/kraken2/index.shtml?t=manual#installation , or use a complete absolute path to your kraken binary when running it e.g.: `/path/to/your/kraken/install/bin/kraken2 --use-names <rest of your command>`

Comment: I think that I am already using the absolute path. you can see it in the picture I added to my post